# How could I get a code for 'Ensure the Equipment continuing uptime and downtime process'

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, cplex, opl, mixed-integer-programming

I am using CPLEX with OPL, and I have trouble specifying a constraint that I need in my model.

Equipment 'A' has a limit uptime to operate, 2 hours. It also has a downtime for maintenance, at least 1 hour.

Each time 't' and total t is 10(discrete).
For example,

```
              t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9 t10  ....
    Equip'A'  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  0   1  .... 
          * downtime is possible to exceed its own maintain time.
```

In this situation,
how can I ensure the continuing uptime process. like not '0 1 0 1', I mean '0 1 1 0 1 1 0' => '1' ,meaning operation, should be adjacent(for ensure continuing uptime).

Every time I run this problem the answer is always depart each '1' for example ' 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1'.

I hope I could get an idea or mathematical way to solve this.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that if your equipment needs 1 hour of maintenance for every 2 hours (or part thereof) of operation; the solution is to replace the equipment. Other than that, cache pending work, so that equipment doesn't start unless there's 2 hours of work for it to do.

Comment: Some 'equipments' need much more maintenance time than actual use time... ;-) https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16121/how-should-the-number-of-maintenance-hours-per-flight-hour-for-the-c-17-be-inter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at consecutive triplets, the patterns `1 1 1` (three hours uptime) and `0 1 0` (single hour uptime) are not allowed.

This can be expressed with linear inequalities (with `t` going from 1 to 8):

```
A[t] + A[t+1] + A[t+2] <= 2 and
A[t+1] <= A[t] + A[t+2]
```

To cover the corner cases (beginning `1 0` or ending `0 1`) you would additionally need:

```
A[1] <= A[2] and
A[10] <= A[9]
```

Comment: Your answer gives me a great insight. Thnx so much. However, there is additional situation, firstly, the operation time could change(cause there are many different equipments, so not only 2 uptime, but also 3 or 4 or 5 and so on....and, downtime also ensured, also can be changed.

Comment: I think this is a perfectly good answer to the question. If the question is not describing the underlying problem precisely enough, then this is a different issue. We can only formulate answers based on information that is available to us. Our mind reading skills are very limited.

Comment: If what you need is to ensure a _minimum_ uptime of `k` hours for equipment `A`, the above answer can be generalized as (with `t` going from `1` to `10-k`): `sum(i in t+1..t+k-1)(A[i]) <= (k-1)(A[t] + A[t+k])`. Basically using a sliding `k+1`-window and disallowing interior elements to be `1` if first and last element are both `0`. Generalized additional constraints to cover the start phase (with `l` going from `2` to `k`): `sum(t in 1..l-1)(A[t]) <= (l-1)(A[l])`. Analogously for the end phase. To ensure minimum _downtime_ replace `A[t]` with `1-A[t]` in the inequalities.

Comment: thnk u so much! :). Your answer will give a great solution for my coding.